# GROUP BY week returning incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've created a query that is meant to calculate the amount of money that I make after subtracting the cost of the products (I don't know the business term) in a given week.

I am meant to get £268.38 but instead I get £203.64 for the week ranging from 2-8 December.

Below is my query, any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT 
            ROUND(SUM(sell_price), 2) AS sell_price, 
            ROUND(SUM((sell_price - 2.8)/100 * 17.25 + 0.49), 2) AS fees, 
            ROUND(SUM(buy_price), 2) AS buy_price, 
            ROUND(SUM(sell_price - ((sell_price - 2.8)/100*17.25+0.49) - buy_price), 2) AS margin, 
            time 
            FROM order_items 
            GROUP BY WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(time), 1) 
            ORDER BY time DESC
```

**UPDATE:**

It's really strange but I'm getting different results in sqlfiddle then I do when I run the query in phpmyadmin

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2d4a/1

Comment: Can you create a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with the strucutre and some sample data?

Comment: @FilipeSilva OK, but it may take a while

Comment: Those places where you add +0.49, you want to add it to the result fo the division, or to the denominator?

Comment: @FilipeSilva to the result of the division and multiplication

Comment: I'm not sure how to go from here. Isn't it possible that the problem is the week you are in? I added a couple of parenthesis to your calculations: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2d4a/12, but i don't get any of the values you mention

Comment: I don't know why I am getting this problem but I think it has something to do with the amount of data I have in that table, there is another 3000 records, if I isolate the week using a WHERE clause e.g `WHERE time > 1203909 AND < 1203909123` it works fine

Comment: Also, ordering by week number is not a good idea, when you start a new year the week number gets reset, meaning results get a bit fuzzy

Comment: *‘It's really strange but I'm getting different results in sqlfiddle then I do when I run the query in phpmyadmin’* – something to do with different time zones, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your select is wrong. If you want to get each weak then you need to change time to WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(time), 1).

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb:

When you select normal columns (like time) AND aggregate functions (like sum, min, max, count), the GROUP BY-clause is always the list of normal columns. (MySQL allows for you to take a subset of normal columns for performance reasons though).

So in your example if you want to have weekly amount, you should select week as Peter suggested and then the aggregate calculations. The group by is then the same week as in select-line.